# WebSocket in UWP crashes with unknown reason

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, uwp, asp.net-core-mvc

I wanna create communication with ASP.NET 5.0 under UWP using WebSockets.

Problem is on line "var response = await socket.ReceiveAsync.."
With following error:

```
    System.Exception: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072EFE
   at Windows.Networking.Sockets.MessageWebSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs.GetDataReader()
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WinRTWebSocket.OnMessageReceived(MessageWebSocket sender, MessageWebSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
```

Code:

```
    async void Initialize(Uri serverAddress)
    {
        tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        token = tokenSource.Token;

        socket = new ClientWebSocket();

        try
        {
            await socket.ConnectAsync(serverAddress, token);

            await Task.Delay(1000);

            byte[] data = new byte[1024];

            var response = await socket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(data), token); // crashes with error HRESULT

            await Task.Delay(1000);

            if (response.EndOfMessage)
            {
                if (response.Count >= data.Length) // error
                    return;

                string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, response.Count);

                PacketData packet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PacketData>(json);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (socket != null)
            {
                socket.Dispose();

                socket = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there something I do wrong?
I tried to run it few times.. Once I get data, but it crashed on "object obj = ..." I checked json value and it was correct, I think it runs okay, but there is something I don't see what's causing crash.

Thanks

**EDIT!**
New code using MessageWebSocket

Error while using code below: "The operation attempted to access data outside the valid range"

```
private void MSocket_MessageReceived(MessageWebSocket sender,               MessageWebSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];

        try
        {
            int length = 0;

            using (DataReader reader = args.GetDataReader())
            {
                reader.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;

                length = (int)reader.UnconsumedBufferLength; // If I create byte[] with length after then it throw same error like in original post.

                reader.ReadBytes(data); // Exception jump
            }

            string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, length);

            PacketData packet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PacketData>(json);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string a = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Init:

```
        mSocket = new MessageWebSocket();
        mSocket.Control.MessageType = SocketMessageType.Binary;
        mSocket.Control.MaxMessageSize = 1024;
        mSocket.MessageReceived += MSocket_MessageReceived;
```

EDIT 2!
Find only working way, its creating array with static size. I don't know how to make it dynamicly. Help me please!

```
        private void MSocket_MessageReceived(MessageWebSocket sender, MessageWebSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[27];

        try
        {
            int length = 0;

            using (DataReader reader = args.GetDataReader())
            {
                reader.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;

                length = (int)reader.UnconsumedBufferLength;

                reader.ReadBytes(data);
            }

            string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, length);

            PacketData packet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PacketData>(json);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string a = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

EDIT3:
Added Array.Resize(ref data, length), seems working, but I don't think is properly.

Comment: How is `Initialize()` called? Avoid `async void ` since you can't `await` it, you should change the method signature to `async Task` and `await Initialize();`.

Comment: Also, waiting a fixed amount of `1000ms` for the answer may cause problems. I don't see why you need to wait between connecting and receiving data. For the `ReceiveAsync`, which you already `await` (but the `WebSocketReceiveResult` still has an `EndOfMessage` property, mysteriously), you could do a simple spin-lock as of `while(!response.EndOfMessage()) Task.Delay(100);`.

Comment: The error means the remote server is closing the connection.

Comment: Maxim: Its called without await, using in constructor.
kiewic: what I need to set to not closing it?

Comment: The delays serve no purpose here; `await` already won't return until the operation is complete

Comment: okay removed, but why I have to call await Initialize? Its will call in next thread isnt it?

Comment: You could first test that your WebSocket server is working correctly by using a JavaScript client like this: https://github.com/kiewic/nodejs-ws-sample/blob/master/client.html

Comment: kiewic: Yes I successfully connect and received 27bytes. I can't decode in your example, but I did successfully connect and received these bytes. I can't decode it because I encoded it with Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(..)
but these 27bytes I successfully received after few times and immediatelly it crashed.

Comment: One more thing, `System.Net.WebSockets` is not available for UWP apps. How are you running the repro? For UWP apps, you can use `Windows.Networking.Sockets.MessageWebSocket`.

Comment: Edited original post, included new code with new error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataReader` class has a [`ReadString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.streams.datareader.readstring.aspx) method, we can use this method to get the received message without using `byte[]` like following:

```
private void MSocket_MessageReceived(MessageWebSocket sender, MessageWebSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        using (DataReader reader = args.GetDataReader())
        {
            reader.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;

            string json = reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength);

            PacketData packet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PacketData>(json);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string a = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

If you still want to use `byte[]`, you can try following code:

```
private void MSocket_MessageReceived(MessageWebSocket sender, MessageWebSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    byte[] data;

    try
    {
        int length = 0;

        using (DataReader reader = args.GetDataReader())
        {
            reader.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;

            length = (int)reader.UnconsumedBufferLength;
            data = new byte[length];

            reader.ReadBytes(data);
        }

        string json = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, length);

        PacketData packet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PacketData>(json);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string a = ex.Message;
    }
}
```